# Aforge.Genetic, фитнесс-функция

Tags: c#, aforge

Нужна помощь с библиотекой `Aforge.Genetic`.

В хромосоме кодирую коэффициенты полинома, используя тип данных `DoubleArrayChromosome`. 
Подскажите синтаксис объявления фитнесс-функции и популяции. Документация в интернете скудная. Буду рад примерам, ссылкам, советам.

Пока что имеется только код объявления хромосомы:

```
AForge.Math.Random.IRandomNumberGenerator chGenerator = 
     new AForge.Math.Random.ExponentialGenerator(0.01f);
DoubleArrayChromosome ch = 
     new DoubleArrayChromosome(chGenerator, chGenerator, chGenerator, 10);
```